# How to call setInputView method to render a different keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I come from a javascript background and this is my first brush with java.

I've been following [this guide](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615). I've got a fully working keyboard and now I'd like to start customizing it. First thing I want to do is to display symbols when a key is pressed.

After digging around it looks like [setInputView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html) might be what I need, but I'm not sure how to call it? There's a switch statement that controls the casing of symbols that I thought I'd be able to hook into but when I call the method I get the error `Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView$OnKeyboardActionListener.onPress(int)' on a null object reference` which I assume is because the function i THINK I'm calling, I'm not actually calling.

The following is the relevant java code I have so far:

package com.example.crhistian.spanishsymbolskeyboard;

```
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
public class SpanishSymbols extends InputMethodService
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener{

private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;
private KeyboardView spanishkv;

private boolean caps = false;

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch(primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE :
            setInputView(spanishkv);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence text) {
}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {
}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {
}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
    spanishkv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.spanishsymbols, null);
    spanishkv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
}

private void playClick(int keyCode){
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch(keyCode){
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: at this line `case Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE :
            setInputView(spanishkv);` I know its because I'm trying to call setInputView wrong but I'm not sure how to do it right

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the listener on the spanish keyboard, something like

```
spanishKv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
```